# Ubuntu 18.04 does not mount 2TB exFat drive even after installing exfat-fuse exfat-utils

Tags: mount, external-hdd, exfat

I've bought a new Seagate Expansion Portable Drive 2TB with exFat format. It works normally on Windows. On Ubuntu 18.04 I tried to mount the HD but failed.

I found advice to install `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` (exfat 1.2.8). I've done that and still the HD is not mounting.

I tried to format the hd to NTFS but failed. I formatted it back with success to exFat. Still Ubuntu does not mount the HD. On disk it just mention 2TB block device. No partition.

Tried to format using mkfs.exfat but I get an Input/Output error. Checking on Windows for drive error found nothing wrong.

Comment: How did you install exFAT? See https://mangolassi.it/topic/17293/ubuntu-18-04-live-exfat/2

Comment: I install using sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils. Then get exfat-fuse  and exfat-utils 1.2.8.

Comment: As in the reference, add PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat`

Comment: Already tried and the result:
Error reading https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&exact=on&search=0xtag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted: Not Found
 
and  error on update:
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Answer (score 13):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and When your terminal appears, Type below command and boom:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Unplug your `exFat` external flash and then plug it again. This way settled my issue. Hope helps you.

Comment: already tried. See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

exfat* was missing from my list as well, and I couldn't find a reliable repo source to add:

```
# apt-get install ex
example-content exim4 exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-heavy  exim4-daemon-light exim4-dev exim4-doc-html exuberant-ctags
```

I ended up downloading it from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fuse-exfat/exfat-fuse_1.2.8-1_amd64.deb).

Then ran `dpkg -i exfat-fuse_1.2.8-1_amd64.deb` to install.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS please use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils --fix-missing
```